# Как пронумеровать элементы TreeViewItem при добавлении?

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте.

Есть такой код. Как пронумеровать дочерние добавляемые по кнопки элементы элементы TreeViewItem при добавлении? Как сделать, чтобы первоначальное значение переменной kx было не 2, а 1 и далее изменялось?

```
public void bb1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (treeviewSectionsSubSect.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        subitems = (TreeViewItem)treeviewSectionsSubSect.SelectedItem;

        if (subitems.IsSelected == true && subitemc.IsSelected != true && subitems.Header.ToString() == "System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel")
        {

            countButtonClick = countButtonClick + 1;

            subitem = new TreeViewItem();

            subname = "Введите подраздел ";

            if (newChilddf.Tag.ToString() == "s1")
            {
                subitem.Tag = newChilddf.Tag.ToString() + "-" + countButtonClick.ToString();
            }

            subitem.Header = subname + subitem.Tag.ToString();

            subitems.Items.Add(subitem);

            descrl = new TreeViewItem();
            descrl.Header = "Термины";
            subitem.Items.Add(descrl);

            subitemc = new TreeViewItem();

            StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();

            Podradzel(sp);

            subitemc.Header = sp;

            subitem.Items.Add(subitemc);

        }
        else if (subitemc.IsSelected == true && subitemc.Header.ToString() == "System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel")
        {

            TreeViewItem subitemchild = new TreeViewItem();

            if (subitem.Tag.ToString() == newChilddf.Tag.ToString() + "-" + countButtonClick.ToString())
            {
                descrl = new TreeViewItem();
                descrl.Header = "Термины";
                subitemchild.Items.Add(descrl);

                subitemchild.Tag = newChilddf.Tag.ToString() + "-" + countButtonClick.ToString() + "-" + kx.ToString();
                subitemchild.Header = "Введите подраздел " + newChilddf.Tag.ToString() + "-" + countButtonClick.ToString() + "-" + kx.ToString();

                subitemc.Items.Add(subitemchild);

                TreeViewItem subitemcv = new TreeViewItem();

                StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();

                Podradzel(sp);

                subitemcv.Header = sp;

                subitemchild.Items.Add(subitemcv);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Добавлено.**

```
int sum = 1;

for (x = 0; x <= newChild.Items.Count; )
{
  sum *= x;
  x++;

  newChild2 = new TreeViewItem();
  newChild2.Header = "Введите подраздел " + i.ToString() + "-" + x.ToString();
  newChild2.Tag = i.ToString() + "-" + x.ToString();

}

newChild.Items.Add(newChild2);
```

Comment: Создай массив типа Object

Comment: Ну создам. А дальше что с ним делать? Возник немного другой вопрос по ходу,
можно ли то же самое сделать рекурсивно и менять значения свойства Tag

                int sum = 1;

                for (x = 0; x <= newChild.Items.Count; )
                {

                    sum *= x;

                    x++;

                    newChild2 = new TreeViewItem();
 newChild2.Header = "Введите подраздел " + i.ToString() + "-" + x.ToString();
                    newChild2.Tag = i.ToString() + "-" + x.ToString();

                }

                newChild.Items.Add(newChild2);
            }